# TLS to protect Docker Daemon not working on Win - where to look in diagnostics files?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-daemon

Anyone know **where to look within the various Docker diagnostics files to diagnose why TLS is not working to protect the Docker Daemon** on Docker Desktop for Windows?

Tried the following article from Docker and countless other articles to try to protect the Docker Engine using a self-signed TLS cert on Windows, but none have worked.

**Use TLS HTTPS to Protect the Docker Daemon Socket**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket

Docker Desktop for Windows versions tried: 2.3.0.4, 3.2.0

OS: Windows 10

The general log file that is produced doesn’t provide a clear answer to the root cause of the issue. **Are there certain files within the diagnostic files, which are generated, that might provide better insight as to why TLS is not working?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug messages on either the command line or add them to daemon.json

command line

```
dockerd --debug
```

daemon.json

```
{
    "debug": true
}
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description

On windows the output will go to the Event Viewer.